# Suitable multiple testing procedure for three very correlated phenotypes

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, computational-statistics

I have ran an analysis using polygenic risk scores including genetic variants at different p-value thresholds and have the following outcomes: IQ ages 8 and 9, strengths and difficulties questionnaire points at 9 and 12 years, and educational attainment points at 5 different ages. Firstly, the polygenic risk score includes genetic variants found associated with attention deficit disorder at different p-values. Would I have to correct the exposure for multiple testing? I am assuming not as the PRS at 5x10^-2 would include all the genetic variants at lower thresholds, etc. Furthermore, cognitive test at age 8 and 15 are also correlated etc.
How should I go about correcting for multiple testing?

independent var is the polygenic risk score examined at different p-value thresholds
dependent var is IQ ages 8 and 9, strengths and difficulties questionnaire points at 9 and 12 years, and educational attainment points at 5 different ages.

Thanks

Comment: Your response variable(s) are ????

Comment: IQ ages 8 and 9, strengths and difficulties questionnaire points at 9 and 12 years, and educational attainment points at 5 different ages.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are doing P+T and are wondering if you need to do multiple comparison testing for p-value threshold. You shouldn't do this (at least not Bonferroni). This is just a selection step.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else struggles with this:
It sounds like you have (something like):
Outcome ~ PRS + IQ@8 + IQ@9 + ...?

In which case you correct for multiple testing using the number of variables you have inserted in your model (i.e. 3  in the model I have described). The PRS is just one input and not the number of genetic variants used for the PRS.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to use any 'correction' for multiple comparisons. The multiple comparisons adjustments are unnecessary and unhelpful in many circumstances. If this is a preliminary study then don't do it. If this is an  analysis to guide further studies (new data) then it is a preliminary study.

If you want to make inferences on the basis of the evidence within these data and any other information then you need to deal with the evidence rather than the long-run error rates that multiplicity adjustments preserve.

I have written about the important distinction between local evidence and global long run errors here: [A Reckless Guide to P-Values](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286).